# Using a column in .txt for calculation

Tags: python, numpy, math

I have a  text file with 5 columns and 36 rows.  I want to pick a specific column and used it in a calculation.

Sample data:

```
#1        2         3          4        5     
50.0  0.000E+00  1.386E+16  3.718E+15  261.9   
60.0  0.000E+00  3.929E+15  1.054E+15  247.5   
70.0  0.000E+00  1.043E+15  2.792E+14  227.9   
80.0  3.425E+09  2.425E+14  6.453E+13  212.8
```

Let's say, I want to select the 3rd, 4th, and 5th column to used it as a calculation.

```
DataIn = loadtxt('filename.txt')
a = DataIn[:,2:3]
b = DataIn[:,3:4]
c = DataIn[:,4:5]
z = DataIn[:,0:1]
```

Calculation:

```
d = a*1.6
e = b*3.2
f = c*2.8
ave = (d + e + f)/3
h = z/ave
```

I want the output as a column and put it in a file with z, e, f, ave, and h.  This part, I am not sure how to do.

Is there a cleaner way to do it?

Any help would be truly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Are they tab or space separated? Does the txt file contain the header?

Comment: @SamyokNepal, the columns are space.  The txt file does not contain header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out.  Thank you everyone for your help.

```
z, a , b, c = loadtxt('filename.txt',unpack=True, usecols=[0, 1, 2, 3])
```

Calculation:

```
d = a*1.6
e = b*3.2
f = c*2.8
ave = (d + e + f)/3
h = z/ave
```

Writing file:

```
import csv
zip(z, e, q1, f, ave, h)
with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as f:
writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')
writer.writerows(zip(z, e, q1, f, ave, h))
```

Answer (score 3):

Loading your data into `pandas` would simplify not just the calculations, but also saving the updated text file.  Below is an example for your `d` calculation.  The data is loaded into a `DataFrame`, the calculation for `d` is performed, which adds a new column to the `DataFrame` then a new file is created with your new column added.

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename.txt', sep=' ', header=None, names=['z', 'a', 'b', 'c'])
df['d'] = df['a']*1.6
df.to_csv('new_file.txt')
```

Comment: I used your codes and I got the following error. `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv('filename.txt', sep=' ', columns=['z', 'a', 'b', 'c'])
TypeError: parser_f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'`

Comment: @Duchess- Oops wrong argument for `read_csv`.  I've fixed this in the code.

Comment: @ vealkind, now I got a different type of error: `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'`

Comment: @Duchess- I cannot recreate this error using the data above.  When the data above is loaded into a DataFrame the values are all floats, so I'm not sure where the sequence is coming from.

Comment: @vealkind It is possible that OP's datatype is type `str` (confirmed datatype `str` in the other answer) instead of `int` or `float`. Maybe using `.astype()` to convert the column datatype to a number would solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why use a package? I do this if I have to loop through some data:

```
txtfile = open("filename.txt", "r")
outfile = open("outfile.txt", "w")
for line in txtfile:
    row = line.split("  ")
    z = float(row[0])
    a = float(row[2])
    b = float(row[3])
    c = float(row[4])
    d = a * 1.6
    e = b * 3.2
    f = c * 2.8
    ave = (d + e + f) / 3
    h = z / ave
    outfile.write(str(z) + "\t" +
                  str(e) + "\t" +
                  str(f) + "\t" +
                  str(ave) + "\t" +
                  str(h) + "\n")
```

Comment: I used your codes and I got the following error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    z = float(row[0])
ValueError: could not convert string to float: #Input parameters`

Comment: Why do you have 7 extra lines? This ran without any packages/imports on my computer. I’ll look into it though.